# How to insert or update in KnowRob?

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wonder if Knowrob (or prolog) has provided functions to insert new items or update current knowledge base? And also save it back to the file...

By the way, what is the best document to start with to use KnowRob?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11624/how-to-insert-or-update-in-knowrob?/) by [Ze JI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1235/ze-ji/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2011-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

the best way to start is to do the tutorials linked on the wiki page for the KnowRob stack: http://www.ros.org/wiki/knowrob

Updating knowledge is of course possible -- the exact way depends on which kinds of knowledge you would like to add. You can always manipulate the Prolog statements directly using rdf_assert/rdf_retract (doc: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/package/semweb.html).

For some often-used things like object poses, there are more convenient methods (have a look at the module comp_cop for predicates for setting object poses or for creating object instances).

cheers
Moritz

P.S. We are currently working on refactoring the stack towards a set of re-usable library components, having better methods for adding, updating and exporting information. They are documented in the source code, but not yet on the wiki page, and we have not yet released them to the public. If you are working more actively with KnowRob, we can make them public or give you access to the internal repository.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2011-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2011-12-07**:
Update: These components have been released as part of knowrob-0.2.0 and are now publicly available in the official KnowRob distribution.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've sent you information via PM how to get access to the KnowRob development repository.

Moritz

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2011-10-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1